# [NSKeyedUnarchiver init]: cannot use -init for initialization' error when trying to save a custom class

Tags: swift, load, nskeyedunarchiver

I get the error:

> [NSKeyedUnarchiver init]: cannot use -init for initialization
>   when trying to load a custom class.

Heres my Init for the class:

```
   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        print("intializing")
        if let quoteName = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("quoteName") as? String {
            self._quoteName = quoteName
        }
        if let quote = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("quote") as? String {
            self._quote = quote
        }
        if let soundFileName = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("soundFileName") as? String {
            self._soundFileName  = soundFileName
        }
        if let soundFileType = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("soundFileType") as? String {
            self._soundFileType = soundFileType
        }
        if let audioFilePath = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("audioFilePath") as? String {
            self._soundFileType = audioFilePath
        }
        if let state = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("state") as? Bool {
            self._state  = state
        }
        if let number = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("number") as? Int {
            self._number = number
        }

    }
```

Heres my Encoder function

```
  func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
            aCoder.encodeObject(self._quoteName, forKey: "quoteName")
            aCoder.encodeObject(self._quote, forKey: "quote")
            aCoder.encodeObject(self._soundFileType, forKey: "soundFileName")
            aCoder.encodeObject(self._soundFileType, forKey: "soundFileType")
            aCoder.encodeObject(self._audioFilePath, forKey: "audioFilePath")
            aCoder.encodeObject(self._state, forKey: "state")
            aCoder.encodeObject(self._number, forKey: "number")
    }
```

Any finally my call to load:

```
    class func loadQuoteList(){
    print("loading Quotes")
    quoteList.removeAll()
    var quoteListLength = defaults.integerForKey("quoteListLength")

    //unarchives Quote Object
    var unarc = NSKeyedUnarchiver()
    if let data = defaults.objectForKey("Quote") as? NSData {
        unarc = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: data)
    }

    print("loading individual quotes")
    for(var index = 0; index < quoteListLength; index++){
        var newQuote = unarc.decodeObjectForKey("Quote\(index)") as! Quote
        quoteList[index] = newQuote
        print(newQuote._quoteName)

    }
}
```

Comment: could you share the code using NSKeyedArchiver to write objects.

why not encode the array of Quotes as one object?